# Python list assignment not working

Tags: python, list, append

So I have a list, and inside a for loop, I append a set of coordinates structured as a list, but once returned, it just contains the last produced coordinate and it replaces all other items in the master list. 
Upon closer inspection, every time I append something, it replaces all items in the master list with the current coordinate.
Why?
And source code probably won't help, it's exactly how it sounds.
Thanks!
Here some code:

```
def createLab(size=16):
maze = createMaze()
answerPath=[]
visual=['o']*(size**2)
pos=[(size**2)/2,(size**2)/2]
lat='north'
for move in maze:
    #print move, lat, pos
    #print answerPath
    answerPath.append(pos)
    #answerPath='[%s, %s]' % (answerPath,pos)
    if move=='straight':
        if lat=='north': pos[1]=pos[1]+size
        elif lat=='south': pos[1]=pos[1]-size
        elif lat=='east': pos[0]=pos[0]+1
        elif lat=='west': pos[0]=pos[0]-1

    elif move=='left':
        if lat=='north': pos[1]=pos[1]-1; lat='west'
        elif lat=='south': pos[1]=pos[1]+1; lat='east'
        elif lat=='east': pos[0]=pos[0]+size; lat='north'
        elif lat=='west': pos[0]=pos[0]-size; lat='south'

    elif move=='right':
        if lat=='north': pos[1]=pos[1]+1; lat='east'
        elif lat=='south': pos[1]=pos[1]-1; lat='west'
        elif lat=='east': pos[0]=pos[0]-size; lat='south'
        elif lat=='west': pos[0]=pos[0]+size; lat='north'
    #print pos
    #print; print
return answerPath, maze, pos
```

Comment: because you probably did `x = some_list` creating a reference or something similar

Comment: please give some codes.

Comment: Probably because you're assigning instead of appending. Please show your code.

Comment: It would probably be better to put in the source code and we'll see whether it helps or not.

Comment: Okay, I added some code, hope it makes sense!... And maze=['straight ','left', etc]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating one `pos` list before the loop, and you're appending the exact same `pos` to `answerPath` over and over again, and modifying the same `pos` over and over again.

As a solution, create a new `pos` at the start of each iteration, using the slice notation to make a shallow copy:

```
def createLab(size=16):
    maze = createMaze()
    answerPath=[]
    visual=['o']*(size**2)
    pos=[(size**2)/2,(size**2)/2]
    lat='north'
    for move in maze:
        pos = pos[:] #pos is now a new list with the same values as the previous pos
        #Alternatively: pos = list(pos)
        answerPath.append(pos)

        if move=='straight':
            if lat=='north': pos[1]=pos[1]+size
            elif lat=='south': pos[1]=pos[1]-size
            elif lat=='east': pos[0]=pos[0]+1
            elif lat=='west': pos[0]=pos[0]-1

        elif move=='left':
            if lat=='north': pos[1]=pos[1]-1; lat='west'
            elif lat=='south': pos[1]=pos[1]+1; lat='east'
            elif lat=='east': pos[0]=pos[0]+size; lat='north'
            elif lat=='west': pos[0]=pos[0]-size; lat='south'

        elif move=='right':
            if lat=='north': pos[1]=pos[1]+1; lat='east'
            elif lat=='south': pos[1]=pos[1]-1; lat='west'
            elif lat=='east': pos[0]=pos[0]-size; lat='south'
            elif lat=='west': pos[0]=pos[0]+size; lat='north'
    return answerPath, maze, pos
```

For a pointer on what's actually going on with `pos` in your example and mine, I recommend reading [Wesley Chun's excellent slides on Python's Memory Model](http://www.oscon.com/oscon2013/public/schedule/detail/29374).

Comment: That worked! How does something so simple work? Was I just referencing it before or something?

Comment: Yes, when you append something to a list, you're effectively storing a reference to the object being appended.  For every iteration of the loop, you were storing a new reference to the same object, then mutating the object - so every reference in the list reflected the same mutation.

Answer (score 0):

Without the code, we can't really help you too much. From your discription, it sounds as if you are not appending the new coordinates to the list, but rather are writing over the same list.

Please provide us with the code in question.

Try something like .append in your code. For example.

list = [one, two, three]

list.append(four)

print(list)

print should now provide you with the following result.

one, two, three, four

I hope this helped you.